# Regular expression in python xxx

Tags: python

```
import re
email="skoal.com abc@com 123@abx.ty.com2 Manan.5587@gmail.com   abc@bhe.com"
print("Email Matches",len(re.findall("[\w._%+-]{1,20}@[\w.-]{2,20}.[A-Za-z]{2-3}",email)))
```

this code should be able to verify correctly entered email addresses but it's not doing it, unable to find error need help as a new learner

was learning this online code seems to be correct but the output I want isnt the one I am getting

I am always getting output as 0

Comment: Right now your  pattern isn't matching anything in your test string. There are some great online tools [like this one](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5B%5Cw._%25%2B-%5D%7B1%2C20%7D%40%5B%5Cw.-%5D%7B2%2C20%7D.%5BA-Za-z%5D%7B2-3%7D&test_string=skoal.com%20abc%40com%20123%40abx.ty.com2%20Manan.5587%40gmail.com%20abc%40bhe.com&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) to help write/test regex for python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing the answer since I don't have commenting privileges. The following works:

```
email="skoal.com abc@com 123@abx.ty.com2 Manan.5587@gmail.com   abc@bhe.com"

print("Email Matches",len(re.findall("[\w._%+-]{1,20}@[\w.-]{2,20}.[A-Za-z]{2,3}",email)))
```

note {2,3} instead of {2-3}

Comment: import re
phone="212-544-1547"
if re.search("\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}",phone):
    print("Its a valid number")
else:
    print("Its not a valid number")

Can u help me with this also sometimes gives correct output and sometimes it doesn't

Its suppose to verifyy entered number form 000-000-0000 like this one

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues.

First use a raw string `r""`. Without the r you're escaping the values incorrectly.

Second, when matching on a dot `.`, you should escape it. Otherwise that will match any character.

Finally `[A-Za-z]{2-3}` is incorrect. You need to do `[A-Za-z]{2,3}`

```
# incorrect
"[\w._%+-]{1,20}@[\w.-]{2,20}.[A-Za-z]{2-3}"

# correct
r"[\w._%+-]{1,20}@[\w.-]{2,20}\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}"
```

Example:

```
import re
emails = "skoal.com abc@com 123@abx.ty.com2 Manan.5587@gmail.com   abc@bhe.com"
regex = r"[\w._%+-]{1,20}@[\w.-]{2,20}\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}"

print("Email Matches:", re.findall(regex, emails))
```

```
Email Matches: ['123@abx.ty.com', 'Manan.5587@gmail.com', 'abc@bhe.com']
```

As a general comment, when writing regular expressions, start simple and work your way up. When debuging, first test `r"[\w._%+-]{1,20}"`, then `r"[\w._%+-]{1,20}@[\w.-]{2,20}"`, etc, until you get the full regex working, and verify you're matching what you expect on each iteration.

Comment: import re
phone="212-544-1547"
if re.search("\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}",phone):
    print("Its a valid number")
else:
    print("Its not a valid number")

Can u help me with this also sometimes gives correct output and sometimes it doesn't

Its suppose to verifyy entered number form 000-000-0000 like this one

Comment: @MananMalhotra did you read this answer? You need to use raw strings r""

Comment: Got it , thanks
tried with  r '' aswell still the output isn't reliable, like if i enter 5 values at end instead of 4 its still shows its valid, i want it to show invalid instead.

Second, when matching on a dot ., you should escape it. Otherwise that will match any character.(also i wasnt able to understand this comment can u elaborate)